# Intuition behind Kronecker's congruence?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The modular polynomial is defined by$$\Phi_n(X, \tau) = \prod_{\tau} (X - j(\tau)),$$where $j$ is the elliptic modular function and $\tau$ is running through classes of imaginary quadratic integers of discriminant $n$. What is an easy way to see that$$\Phi_p(X, Y) \equiv (X - Y^p)(X^p - Y) \text{ (mod }p \text{)},$$i.e. what is the intuition behind Kronecker's congruence?

Comment: What is $j$?  If $Y$ is an indeterminate, how is $\alpha(Y)$ meaningful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming that the modular polynomial you are talking about is the same one as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_modular_curve), although I don't see how to make that description match up with yours. For that one, if $X = j(\tau)$, then the roots of $\Phi_p(X, Y)$ are $j(\tau/p)$, $j((\tau+1)/p)$, $j((\tau+2)/p)$, ..., $j((\tau+p-1)/p)$ and $j(p \tau)$.

The motivation for this is as follows. Let $\Lambda$ be the free $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice spanned by $1$ and $\tau$. Then $\Lambda$ has $p+1$ index-$p$ sublattices: $\mathrm{Span}(p, \tau)$, $\mathrm{Span}(p, 1+\tau)$, ..., $\mathrm{Span}(p, \tau+p-1)$ and $\mathrm{Span}(1, p \tau)$. Call these lattices $\Lambda_j$. Thus, the elliptic curve $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ has a degree $p$ isogeny from the $p+1$ elliptic curves $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_j$. Since rescaling $\Lambda_j$ by a scalar won't change the corresponding quotient curve, we may equally well work with $\mathrm{Span}(1, \tau/p)$, $\mathrm{Span}(1, (1+\tau)/p)$, ..., $\mathrm{Span}(1, (\tau+p-1)/p)$ and $\mathrm{Span}(1, p \tau)$.

Recall that the classical modular function $j(\tau)$ is the $j$-invariant of the elliptic curve $\mathbb{C}/\mathrm{Span}(1, \tau)$. So we see that, for elliptic curves $E_1$ and $E_2$ over $\mathbb{C}$, there is a degree $p$ isogeny $E_1 \to E_2$ if and only if $\Phi_p(j(E_1), j(E_2))=0$.

Now, the intuition for the question you ask about is that this result works not only over $\mathbb{C}$, but also over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. And so the key result is that, for $E_1$ and $E_2$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, there is a degree $p$ isogeny between $E_1$ and $E_2$ if and only if either $E_2$ is the Frobenius image of $E_1$ (in which case $j(E_2) = j(E_1)^p$) or vice versa (in which case $j(E_1) = j(E_2)^p$). See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19390/intuition-behind-the-eichler-shimura-relation?rq=1) for more on this.

But I think that to make this intuition more precise, you are going to want to learn a lot more about how to talk about elliptic curves in the modern language of algebraic geometry. Have you worked through Silverman's books yet? That is the usual start.

Answer (score 8):

David Speyer posted his answer while I was typing, and it's great, but here's a slightly different take.

Consider a generic curve $E/\mathbb C_p$ having multiplicative reduction. Then $E/\mathbb C_p$ has a Tate model,
$$ E(\mathbb C_p) \cong \mathbb C_p^*/q^{\mathbb Z}, $$
where $q\in\mathbb C_p$ satisfies $0<|q|<1$. What are the curves $p$-isogenous to $E$. Letting $Q=q^{1/p}$ ($Q$ is any of the $p$'th roots of $q$), it's a nice exercise to check that they are the curves
$$ E_\zeta := \mathbb C_p^*/(\zeta Q)^{\mathbb Z} \quad\hbox{and}\quad E_0:=\mathbb C_p^*/(q^p)^{\mathbb Z},$$
where  $\zeta$ is any primitive $p$'th root of unity.
(These correspond to the subgroups $\boldsymbol\mu_p$ and $\langle\zeta Q\rangle$.)

From the $q$-expansion of the $j$-invariant, we have
$$ j(E) = q^{-1} + 744 + 196884q + \cdots, $$
So
$$ \Phi_p(X) = (X-j(q^p))\prod_\zeta (X-j(\zeta Q)) .$$
We have $j(q^p)\equiv j(q)^p\pmod{p}$, while the product looks like
$$
  \prod_\zeta (X-j(\zeta Q)) = \prod_\zeta (X-(\zeta Q)^{-1} - \cdots)
  = (X^p - Q^{-p} + \cdots) = (X^p-q^{-1} + \cdots) = (X^p-j(q) + \cdots).
$$
(I'm being a bit imprecise here, but we're looking at neighborhood of $q=0$, and
the dots represent lower order terms as $q\to0$.) Putting it together, we get
$$ \Phi_p(X) \equiv (X-j(q)^p)(X^p-j(q))\pmod{p}. $$
N.B. I'm not suggesting that this is a rigorous proof. But you asked for some intuition. For me, (1) it's always been writing $E/K$ as $K^*/q^{\mathbb Z}$ that's explained Kronecker; (2) you can turn this into a proof over $\mathbb C$ by being a bit more careful with the $q$ expansions; (3) you can also make the proof I've sketched over $\mathbb C_p$ rigorous with more work.

Of course, the fancy way to express it is that when you reduce the Hecke correspondence $T_p$ modulo $p$, you get $\Phi_p+\Phi_p^t$, the sum of the graph of Frobenius and it's transpose.